# Cannot run project by CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have problem with my project. Because this is a secret, I can not publish my site here. I am sorry for this and this is my case.

I have a project based on the CodeIgniter framework, I run it successfully on localhost but when I use SVN to commit this project to my hosting. It do not run. I am trying to delete all file and commit only index.html with content is "test". Browser show result is "test". I am trying to commit this project again but result still is "test".

However, if I type index.php after my url "http://myaddress.com/index.php", I see my result which I would like. I have tried to config file "config.php" remove "index.php" in `$config['index.php] = ''` but nothing changes.

Comment: Check mode rewrite in enabled on your server ?

Comment: It could be your htaccess here are some more examples https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CodeIgniter's doc, check the "Remove the index.php file" on this page: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html

And just to remember, have you enabled Apache's mod_rewrite?

Comment: Tks for your help Joaobarbosa, I build my project follow this link and my project run successfully on localhost without "index.php". But it was not success on hosting. I need find to where I was wrong? :)

Comment: @joaobarbosa Both docs now found here for codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/docs CI2 versions and CI3

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep which hosting service are you using? does it support apache's mod_rewrite and .htaccess files? is it linux or windows? can you give any other information about it, and maybe, post your config files, so we can validate it?

Comment: Thanks so much Joaobarbosa. I am contacting with system admin to check mod_rewrite and waiting his feedback, If this case still do not solve, I will ask you more than. Thanks :)

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep glad to help :)

Comment: @joaobarbosa Admin said module rewrite was turned on and my case was not solved. Could you help me?

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep sure. Can you ask him if .htaccess files are enabled? Because, maybe mod_rewrite is on, but Apache rules doesn't allow .htaccess files :)

Comment: @joaobarbosa I think so. Because He said that he has deleted www root folder and upload source again. Then, I try access to http://myaddress.com. The result has shown correct. But when I would like to access http://myaddress.com/controller. I must be type index.php after myaddress.com. Althought I have configed in file "config.php". I will ask him again and tell to you the result. Tks so much

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep you're welcome! please keep me up to date

Comment: @joaobarbosa Tks for your help. this case was solved. Problem about this host do not allow file .htaccess. It allow web.config. :) Tks so much.

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep great :) so, it was a windows server, right?

Comment: @joaobarbosa I can not check but i think so :)

Comment: @thanhoangxuannghiep it probably is, because web.config files are known as IIS config files :)

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file with the following rule in root folder,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

To make .htaccess work , you have to enable apache module `mod_rewrite`

If you have access to server, you can type the following command in the terminal (for linux servers, this example specific to ubuntu)

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

If you have not access to server, please contact server administrator.